# Word for being aware of something but not doing anything about it?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, adjectives

To expand on the title more, is there an adjective for someone that is aware of something happening but is not doing anything about it, even though they could interfere but they're just not choosing too?

Here's an example: let's say that there's a toddler at a daycare. The toddler starts stealing toys from other kids and gets into fights with them. The daycare supervisors are completely aware that this is happening, and they can intervene, but they choose not to.

I tried the words ignorant and oblivious but that doesn't work since the person is aware it's happening. I also can't think of any other word that works. If someone could help, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: inaction, indifferent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an **adjective** for "someone that is aware of something..."

You may say they are **unconcerned** about what's going on around them.

> - **unconcerned** - (adjective) not involved, not having any part or interest. It suggests a lack of sensitivity or regard for others' needs or troubles "unconcerned about the homeless". [**MW**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unconcerned) - -  Not involved or interested, indifferent [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unconcerned)

- "a good parent will never be **unconcerned** about the education of their children"
- "The question then is how a person can have self-respect if they are **unconcerned** about their own interests"
- "A sensible adviser ought not to be **unconcerned** about the influence which his writings may have on the public"

Comment: The supervisors connived at the theft of the toys.

Comment: @Airymouse  The OP is asking for an adjective.

Comment: @Centarus How about "the conniving supervisors ignored the theft of the toys?"  My own problem with this answer is that "conniving" is so often misused as meaning scheming that the statement might be misunderstood.

Comment: You can be concerned but still do nothing, so this may not fit. Although it's unclear.

Answer (score 2):

How about *ignore* or *turn a blind eye to*?

M-W:

> [*ignore*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ignore): to do
>   nothing about or in response to (something or someone)

TFD:

> [*turn a blind eye to*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+a+blind+eye+to):
>   deliberately overlook, ignore

Also *deliberately overlook*. From M-W:

> [*overlook*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypocrisy): to
>   pay no attention to (something)

Your example:

> The daycare supervisors are completely aware that this is happening,
>   and they can intervene, but they choose not to. They choose to
>   *ignore* [or *overlook*] it.
>
> The daycare supervisors are completely aware that this is happening,
>   and they can intervene, but they choose not to. They *turn a blind
>   eye* to it.

Comment: you have _blink_ instead of _blind_ I tried to correct it myself, but my edit wasn't 6 characters long...

Comment: Someone down voted this answer. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The word I believe you are looking for is **negligence**.

Neg•li•gence
noun
failure to take proper care in doing something.
"some of these accidents are due to negligence"

Similar:
carelessness
lack of care
dereliction of duty
nonperformance of duty
non-fulfillment of duty
remissness
neglectfulness
neglect
laxity
laxness
irresponsibility
inattention
inattentiveness
heedlessness
thoughtlessness
unmindfulness
forgetfulness
slackness
sloppiness
contributory negligence
culpa
barratry
delinquency
disregardfulness
inadvertence
inadvertency
oscitation

Opposite:
conscientiousness
attention to duty

LAW
failure to use reasonable care, resulting in damage or injury to another.

Comment: What's the source of this definition?

Answer (score 0):

I would say **unmoved**

> not changed in one's purpose or intention.

Answer (score 0):

Indifferent or indifference is closest, in my opinion. Perhaps complacency or complacent should also be on the list of choices.

Comment: This would benefit from an authoritative definition.  Please take a moment for the site [tour] and the [FAQ] on how to answer, and welcome to EL&U.